# Queue Selector With Spring HornetQ

Tags: spring, hornetq

I am newbie to HornetQ. I have seen the queue selector example in hornetQ. How to achieve same in Spring integration with HornetQ ? 
Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MessageListenerContainer for consuming messages, check [How to inject a message selector to message listener bean in jms-spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820306/how-to-inject-a-message-selector-to-message-listener-bean-in-jms-spring-integrat)

Comment: Thanks for your reply MojFar. In my case i will only come to know selector detialsin startup only.